# MOSFET allowing current without applied gate voltage

Tags: power, mosfet, led, esp32

I have the following circuit, with [this MOSFET](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2212231008_GOFORD-G08N03D2_C840059.pdf). When I power the 12 V rail, I am getting light out of the [LEDs](https://look.ams-osram.com/m/45b4f97af8741811/original/GW-JTLPS1-EM_GEN-2.pdf), even with 0 voltage applied from the ESP32 I/O (PWM_6500K_IO16)...

[image: circuit design]

I [simulated it](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0wIBxgCwGYBsl8FcB2LHETAJhCQUhoFMBaMMAKADcLtrLjqc1MAE5q9epnpgxUZAjZhcAnuFE1KaVbxAATBgDMAhgFcANgBcmphjvCzx0SvMXUlmLSH5S11PUbOW1rYQ4shOCkrqmiKulO4xIL4GJhZWNnahMOEunpTe1Bi4Hkn%20qUEZ9o7y%20iDC0omQmoUNmipg0EgwkJRsAOYgzZRxA4qJaJrifdy8-NMg2Hj2nOCQkolEK2t5E7JrnZXyAO61mO7bm-TnkFNgq5cbt1vjSwDOtfXnwqctshBGpi8GGw8JpBB5sAghGpJiCRkUEs0yEsgA) and it doesn't seem like it should pass anything, what am I missing?

Comment: If the LEDs are bright, chances are you've got a short under the DFN. Having no series resistors on the LEDs is not ideal, but that's unrelated.

Comment: Double-check that you don't have source and drain backwards.

Comment: Does MOSfet source connect back to ESP32 GND? Schematic doesn't show this connection.

Comment: Is the I/O pin set to output?

Comment: In addition to trying what is in the answers, if there is ripple on the 12V, the Cds of the capacitance will be a conduction path for the ripple component. So check the ripple magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this may not be the cause of your problems, this MOSFET has up to 1μA leakage current, even when it's supposed to be off. This figure comes from page 2 of the datasheet, a parameter called "Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current".

That's enough to make the LEDs glow slightly. The solution is to provide another path *around* the LEDs for this current, a path with significantly lower impedance than the LEDs at that particular point on their IV curve. 10kΩ should do the trick, R3 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAvHzq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also notice R4. This will keep M1 switched firmly off in the case where the GPIO pin is high impedance, during which time the gate is "floating" and whose potential is liable to fluctuate under the influence of all manner of interference from the environment.

Lastly, notice the parasitic body diode inside the MOSFET. If you have swapped drain and source (flipped the MOSFET upside down), this diode will conduct current even if the MOSFET is completely off, and you will not be able to extinguish the LEDs.

---

#### Update

Since this problem is manifest only during MCU start-up, this points to a pull-up resistor raising gate potential during that period, the simplest solution for which is indeed a smaller value for pull-down resistor R4.

You mentioned 22kΩ working, which would suggest that the "weak pull-up" is around 100kΩ or so. With R4=100kΩ this would result in a gate potential of approximately half the supply, about 1.6V, enough to produce significant drain current. By reducing R4 to 22kΩ, during startup you now have gate potential \$V_G = 3.3V \times \frac{22k\Omega }{100k\Omega + 22k\Omega } = 0.6V\$.

That's still a little high, and I would recommend going even lower with R4. Given that the GPIO is able to source 20mA (once it has been initialised as an output), we may choose R4 as low as \$\frac{3.3V}{20mA}=170\Omega\$ without breaking anything.

We should also consider limiting gate charge current, using another resistor, to ensure that the GPIO is never asked for more current than it is rated for. I think the following design should work fine:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flngpv.png)</sup>

This will result in a gate potential of approximately \$3.3V \times \frac{4.7k\Omega }{4.7k\Omega + 100k\Omega }=150mV\$ during startup, and gate currents not exceeding \$\frac{3.3V}{470\Omega }=7mA\$ during PWM switching.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! I found out this is close to working... Turns out there's a weak pull up resistor on the pin I'm using (see this datasheet, page 63, https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf). I had to add a 22k pulldown resistor to the gate and it's mostly off - may need to go even lower pulldown for full shutoff. If you want to add this to your answer, I'd be happy to accept, otherwise I can make a new answer

Comment: @joshp R4=100kΩ is plenty, and that internal pull-up resistor shouldn't prevent the GPIO pin from getting all the way to 0V. If 100kΩ doesn't do it, then something else is going on. IMO using a smaller R4 isn't a good general solution, even if it does work in your case. It would prevent GPIO output potential rising all the way to +3.3V, which is equally bad. In any case, it seems odd for the ESP32 to employ an output pull-up resistor if the output is configured for PWM, since that would imply an open-drain output, which you should *not* be using.

Comment: I don't know, it only happens during the boot up phase, once the micro is chugging, the resistors are completely unnecessary...

Comment: @joshp And there's your answer. I was under the impression this was happening all the time, not just for a brief period when the MCU was initiialising. There may be a few ways to overcome this temporary condition, but a smaller R4 is the simplest. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: awesome, thanks! accepted and very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The gate of the MOSFET is high-impedance and a small amount of leakage current can enhance the channel enough to give some conduction.  Add a pull-down resistor from the gate to ground and that should bleed off any stray gate charge.

Comment: I sure that you mean the pulldown should be from gat e to source?

Comment: Yes, between the gate and source.